# How to self join table on rows not equal

Tags: mysql

How can I self join a table where the row is not equal but each individual column may be equal (without checking each individual column)? For example, say I have a table with columns col1, col2, col3 and I want to do something like

```
select * from table T1, table T2 where T1.col1 != T2.col1 or T1.col2 != T2.col2 or T1.col3 != T2.col3
```

In other words, I want all the pairs except the ones paired with themselves, but without having to check each column. The table does not have a unique key (but each row is unique). Please do not tell me to just add a unique key, that isn't the point of the question. Thanks!

Comment: you'd have to specify the columns still, how else would it know what you want?
`WHERE CONCAT(T1.col1,T2.col2,T3.col3) != CONCAT(T2.col1,T2.col2,T2.col3)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a query with not equal to condition then you shoud use '<>'.

Try this query :

```
select * from table T1, table T2 where T1.col1 <> T2.col1 or T1.col2 <> T2.col2 or T1.col3 <> T2.col3
```

Comment: That's almost exactly my query, I wanted a query where I don't have to list all the rows